# make parts of python list from value of arr[i] in loop

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [1,4,16,64]
right = []
left = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    pass

i = 1 || arr[1] = 4 || left = [1] || right = [16,64]
i = 2 || arr[2] = 16 || left = [1,4] || right = [64]
```

make two parts of the list as per the value of arr[i].Example: if i =1 the value is 4.Then all value less than 4 in the list should go on the left list and all values greater than 4 should go on right

Comment: what have you tried so far? SO should be your last resort not your first when you have homework to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the list. The left can be from the beginning to i, and the right from i+1 to the end

```
list1 = [1, 4, 16, 64].sort()
right = []
left = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    right = list1[i+1:]
    left = list1[:i]
    print(f"i = {i} || arr[{i}] = {list1[i]} || left = {left} || right = {right}")
```

Output:

```
i = 0 || arr[0] = 1 || left = [] || right = [4, 16, 64]
i = 1 || arr[1] = 4 || left = [1] || right = [16, 64]
i = 2 || arr[2] = 16 || left = [1, 4] || right = [64]
i = 3 || arr[3] = 64 || left = [1, 4, 16] || right = []
```

Comment: This assumes the list is sorted though

Comment: Question states `all value less than 4 in the list should go on the left list and all values greater than 4 should go on right`. In your solution if the list is let's say sorted in reverse, numbers >4 would be on the left and numbers <4 on the right, the opposite of what op wants OP

Comment: AAALex123, you are correct. But this could be easily be fixed by sorting the list before the loop

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
list1 = [1,4,16,64]
right = []
left = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] <= 4:
        left.append(list1[i])
    else:
        right.append(list1[i])
    print(f"i = {i} || arr[{i}] = {list1[i]} || left = {left} || right = {right}")
```

Output:

```
i = 0 || arr[0] = 1 || left = [1] || right = []
i = 1 || arr[1] = 4 || left = [1, 4] || right = []
i = 2 || arr[2] = 16 || left = [1, 4] || right = [16]
i = 3 || arr[3] = 64 || left = [1, 4] || right = [16, 64]
```

Comment: What? He wanted all values lesser than or equal to 4 in one list and the rest in another.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? It is absolutely right. Why do u keep downvoting?

Comment: ex: [1,3,9,9,27,81] .. i = 1 [1] and [9,9,27,81] . i =2  [1,3]  [9,27,81] .i=3 [1,3,9] [27,81].i=4 [1,3,9,9] [81]  .i=5 [1,2,9,9,27] [] .first list in every iteration is left and second one is right.

Comment: Check out my edit. U can use this code to perform this operation even on an unsorted list.